# MySQL: GRANT effected 0 rows a bug or by design?

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I was successfully able to grant a user limited permissions to a specific database...

---

```
C:\mysql\>mysql -uroot -p
```

Enter password:

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON jabcre5_examplecom.* TO 'test1'@'localhost';
```

Query OK, **0 rows affected** (0.00 sec)

---

...I was thrown off by "**0 rows affected**". After checking everything the user did have the permissions that I had assigned it so...

Is "0 rows affected" a bug or by design?

The reason I am asking this is because there is no question dedicated to clarifying this, since I try to be as thorough as possible I often find what I question to be questioned by others so a solid answer would certainly save some people the time of having to question themselves and merely test out their user/database with a quick query or two.

I've tagged this question with bug as this was certainly unexpected behavior by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by design, confirmed from a MySQL bug report here...
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64313

Answer (score 2):

By design, see the user comments at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html